# Why does my Design view display HTML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this simple project using C#, I copied it from one computer to another. But instead of viewing the design in Design view, all I can see is some HTML (tags and text). 
Why is this happening?

Here's the contents of what I see in Design view, no matter what I do:

> `<html>`One or more errors encountered while loading the designer. The errors are listed below. Some errors can be fixed by rebuilding your project, while others may require code changes.Could not find type 'ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.KryptonNavigator'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.`</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're in Design view, you're probably viewing **Source**. Click the **Design** button (or the **Split** button for a combined view).

[image]

Since that's still not working for you, the error message seems to indicate that `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.KryptonNavigator` is an assembly that was on the computer you copied the project from, but not on the new computer. The assembly is still referenced from within your project, but it's not actually on your computer -- hence the exception.

Comment: Still the HTML code is displayed. I have already tried to click the designers view in all aspects.

Comment: @Stupefy101 Strange. Could you take a screenshot and post it so we can take a look?

Comment: @Stupefy101 You _are_ using Visual Studio, right? I don't think your HTML will make a difference...

Comment: `<html>One or more errors encountered while loading the designer. The errors are listed below. Some errors can be fixed by rebuilding your project, while others may require code changes.Could not find type 'ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.KryptonNavigator'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. </html>
`

Comment: I can see that there is an error on my design view since I don't didn't properly install Krypton that makes me unable to view the design properly.

Comment: @Stupefy101 My guess is that `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Navigator.KryptonNavigator` is an assembly that was on the computer you copied the project from, but not on the new computer. The assembly is still referenced from within your project, but it's not actually on your computer, hence the exception.

Comment: Where can i find the reference and change this?

Comment: @Stupefy101 I can't answer that for you, it looks like some sort of third-party library that your project uses. You'll likely need to install it on the new computer. View your references by clicking on "References" under your project in Solution Explorer within Visual Studio.